# Confused about multivariate analyses

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, manova, multivariate-regression

I have a dataset with three categorical predictors and four continuous response variables. The response variables are various measurements of the subjects' behaviour and they are fairly highly correlated with one another (R = 0.5-0.7).

I want to see if there is an association between the predictor variables and each of the response variables. However, I am wary of just running multiple tests of significance, and I know that multivariate analysis is supposed to be a solution to this.

I was never taught about multivariate analysis in my stats classes so I have been searching online and reading what I can find about multivariate regression and MANOVA in the hope of using a multivariate test to analyse these data. Unfortunately I am struggling to understand what I'm supposed to do. I use R so I found the package "heplots" and the function "robmlm" but there is very little information in the documentation about why it is different from using separate regressions and therefore I don't understand what it's doing. I've also run a MANOVA and, while I can assume that the results are telling me about the effect of each predictor on the response variables overall, I'm not sure how I can find out the effect of each predictor on each response.

Can anyone help at all?